# Google Action Console: Privacy Policy not accepted

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

does anyone know more about this problem? In the menu item "Deploy" you have to link a valid privacy policy. I have created a separate privacy policy for a customer for Google Action only and uploaded it as a PDF to the customer web server. I link this PDF in the Action Console. Google keeps rejecting the Action for the following reason:

> Your Action violates our Privacy & Security policies. The privacy policy URL you provided is invalid. Your privacy policy URL must link to a valid website containing a privacy policy specific to your Action. It must be a public document that discloses how your Action collects, uses, and shares user data, including the types of parties it is shared with. It must be written in each of the languages your Action is enabled for.
>   In your case the privacy policy leads to an Error 403 page, please provide a URL that leads directly to a valid privacy policy.

There is NO 403! There is a valid Privacy Policy specific to my Action. It is a public document and includes everything Google wants. It is written in German which is the only language the Action is enabled for.

I'm desperate about it. My submission has been rejected at least 10 times. Now I am at the end of my possibilities!

Answer (score 1):

Your link does seem to go to a 403 error for me.

[image]

Maybe the document is publicly available in your network, but from the outside you cannot reach it. So I think this is why your action has been declined.

You can try testing using an incognito window to ensure you aren't logged in to the site.